# SSR With Jhipster spring boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, jhipster

I createt a spring boot angular application with jhipster .now I want to optimise my application seo for doing that i have to serve my application templates from server .

my question is how to make generation jhipster spring boot angular  app to a server side redering app

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt you can do it easily. Angular SSR on Java never went beyond experimental projects. See https://github.com/swaechter/angularj-universal/issues/38

You would probably have more luck serving your angular app from a node server using Angular universal https://angular.io/guide/universal

It should be easier if you generate your client separately https://www.jhipster.tech/separating-front-end-and-api/